# CSS media query not applying

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm using this media query in my main css stylesheet and it doesn't seem to be working.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 768px) {
    .small { display: block; }
    .big { display: none !important;}
}
```

In the web inspector it doesn't even show up as a rule, however when i look in the sources panel the query is obviously there. So i'm not sure what the problem could be. I am trying to target devices with a width less than 768px.

Here's how i'm linking to the stylesheet, if that matters
`<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="{site_url}interface/style.css" />`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you are using `max-device-width` it won't affect in web browsers, You should check on mobile browsers to see its working or not.

Or if you want to check on web browsers, Then use just `max-width` instead.

See **[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ENue9/1/)**

CSS

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
    .small { display: block; }
    .big { display: none;}
}
```

Comment: @NoobEditor Thanks. Waiting to reach `1K`