# CSS - Media Query Not Rendering in Browser

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm working on a WordPress site and trying to apply media query styles to a specific ID:

HTML:

```
<div class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="/wp-content/themes/TheBullshitCollection/Images/white-background.jpg">
    <div class="welcome-page-div">
    <h3 id="welcome-cursive">Welcome</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="welcome-page-div">
    <h3>To the Bullshit Collection</h3>
    </div>

    <section id="section5" class="demo">
    <a href="#menu-main"><span></span>Scroll</a>
    </section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* MEDIA QUERIES */

/* SMART PHONE */

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    #welcome-cursive {
        font-size: 270px!important;
    }

    .welcome-page-div h3 {
        font-size: 270px;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to make the h3 with the ID `welcome-cursive` get a font size of 270px at width 320px and below. I already looked at this article: [CSS media query not applying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20877986/css-media-query-not-applying)

My stylesheet is enqueued in the `functions.php` file and is included in the header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://thebullshitcollection.com/wp-content/themes/TheBullshitCollection/css/bullshit.css">
```

Yet the media query doesn't show up in the inspector. Here's my website: http://thebullshitcollection.com/

And it works in JSFiddle as expected:
https://jsfiddle.net/6gmzps4o/

Also I tried adding this to the media query:

```
.welcome-page-div h3 {
    font-size: 270px;
}
```

Yet still no result : (

Comment: It works for me,  just be sure that you cleared you browser cache (ctrl+f5).

Comment: Is there a way to do that with a mac? (google chrome)

Comment: @HappyHands31 try `font-size: 270px !important;`? in your code you missing a space between 270px and !important

Comment: @FAROUKBLALOU It does seem to be a caching issue. It works in Firefox, I just can't seem to clear cache in Google Chrome on my Mac.

Comment: To clear chrome cache in a MAC :  hold down ⌘ Cmd and ⇧ Shift and then press R.

Comment: I tried `Command` + `Shift` + `R` but still no media queries show in Google Chrome. Also tried `Command` + `Shift` + `Delete` to bring up "Clear Browsing Data" module where you can clear cached images and files manually, but still no result in Google Chrome. Also tried quitting and restarting Google Chrome. Does anyone else see the media queries in Chrome? Will try restarting my computer next.

Answer (score 1):

Try do add on head section meta viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```